# how to control rate limits inside a nodejs loop

Tags: node.js, express, request, queue

I am implementing nodejs middleware to send multiple get request(100) to an external API with a loop,
but because of rate limits, I can't send a lot of requests at a time so I want to know if there is a way I can send each request after a certain time  like **100 requests - wait 15min - 100 requests - wait 15min** I have tried to use throttle method but it doesn't seem to works

```
router.get('/activities/:stravaId',limiter,(req, res,done) => {

const userc=req.user;
const access_token=userc.access_token;



var _=require("underscore");
var fs=require("fs");
const ids=[5312632886,
    4952161622,....
]//100 ids
for (let i = 0; i <ids.length ; i++) {

    strava = new stravaApi.client(access_token);
   strava.activities.listLaps({ id:ids[i]},async function (err, payload) {
        if (!err) {
           console.log(payload)
            // await throttle()



            // fs.writeFile("activity-streams.json", JSON.stringify(payload), err => {
            //     if (err) throw err;
            //     console.log("Done writing"); // Success
            // var obj1 = payload ;
            //
            //
            // const result = mergeJSON.merge(obj1, obj1) ;

            //done!

            //
            // console.log(result) ;
            fs.appendFile("streamjson.json", JSON.stringify(payload), err => {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("Done writing"); // Success
            });

        } else {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
}
```

})

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to Handle rate limits error in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68211583/how-to-handle-rate-limits-error-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why do you want to do it, but you can use `setInterval` which can invoke the method after specific interval of time. You should use [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) as it will be more appropriate for your scenario.

```
setInterval(() =>{
    run method
}, 900000);
```

Recommended option when the timings are more, for Node-schedule:

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

const job = schedule.scheduleJob('*/15 * * * *', () => {
  console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
```

Comment: Does this help?